# How to convert large binary to decimal?

Tags: java

It works when I enter binary like 10, 1011, 1101. But it always prints "Not binary" when I enter 10011010010, whereas it should be 1234. How to modify it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Binary {

    public static int toDecimal(String b) {     
        int decimal = Integer.parseInt(b,2);
        return decimal;
    }


    public static boolean isBinary(String b) {
        int inputNum = Integer.parseInt(b);

        while(inputNum != 0){
            if(inputNum % 10 > 1){
                return false;
            }
            inputNum = inputNum / 10;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Enter binary: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String binaryNum = in.next();

        try{
            int intNum = Integer.parseInt(binaryNum);

            boolean isBinary = isBinary(binaryNum);
            if(isBinary){
                int outputDecimal = toDecimal(binaryNum);
                System.out.println("\n"+ outputDecimal +" in decimal");
            }else{
                System.out.println("\n" + "Not binary!");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("\n" + "Not binary!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason to use such a convoluted `isBinary()` algorithm?

Comment: Why not mark the best answer as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)? You can do that by clicking on the hollow tick next to the answer. This will increase your rep too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to parse a number that exceeds
 `Integer.MAX_VALUE` [which is 2^31 - 1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE):

```
int intNum = Integer.parseInt(binaryNum);
```

Try using [`Long.parseLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29) instead. A `long` has 64 bits and has a range of `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` which should be enough to cover your various inputs (although obviously will fail for longer numbers).

Comment: It still print "Not binary" when I entered 10011010010.

Answer (score 2):

Why so many conversions from string to int? Keep the input in string form for checking if the input is binary or not. Then finally convert the string to number type. If you think your input will not exceed the maximum int value, you can use `parseInt()` otherwise use either `long` or `BigInteger`.

With input as string, your `isBinary()` may look like this:

```
public static boolean isBinary(String b) {
    for(int i=0; i<b.length(); i++) {
        if(b.charAt(i) != '0' && b.charAt(i) != '1') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then change all your `Integer.parseInt()` calls to `long.parseLong()`, and change the associated variables accordingly, ie from int to long. That should be enough to get what you expect, for now. What I mean is for arbitrarily large inputs, you have to use BigInteger (see below).

---

If you choose to use [`java.math.BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String,%20int)), you can use the constructor with the radix like so:

```
public static BigInteger toDecimal(String b) {
    return new BigInteger(b, 2);
}
```

Comment: @Andrew I think maybe combining Sнаđошƒаӽ's BigInteger and my pattern would be a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This works although it would be more efficient to process more than 1 bit at a time.  Result for 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 is 9,223,372,036,854,775,808

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

...

public static BigDecimal toDecimal(String b) {     
    BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(b.charAt(0)=='1'?1:0);
    BigDecimal two = new BigDecimal(2);
    for (int i = 1; i<b.length(); i++) {
        bd1 = bd1.multiply(two);
        bd1 = bd1.add(new BigDecimal(b.charAt(i)=='1'?1:0));
    }
    return bd1;
}

public static boolean isBinary(String b) {
    return Pattern.compile("[01]+").matcher(b).matches();
}    

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter binary: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String binaryNum = in.next();

    try{
        boolean isBinary = isBinary(binaryNum);
        if(isBinary){
            BigDecimal outputDecimal = toDecimal(binaryNum);
            System.out.println("\n"+ outputDecimal +" in decimal");
        }else{
            System.out.println("\n" + "Not binary!");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("\n" + "Not binary!");
    }
}
```

More minimal version with use of BigInteger

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter binary: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String binaryNum = in.next();

    try{
        if(Pattern.compile("[01]+").matcher(binaryNum).matches()){
            BigInteger outputDecimal = new BigInteger(binaryNum, 2);
            System.out.println("\n"+ outputDecimal +" in decimal");
        }else{
            System.out.println("\n" + "Not binary!");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("\n" + "Not binary!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why BigDecimal? And why convert to decimal manually, when we can use constructor that takes in input radix argument?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ Yes. I wasn't aware of the BigInteger radix constructor - it's perfect. I used BigDecimal because it's 2 in the morning and the code already referred to decimals. bad choice.  I would delete the answer if I didn't prefer my `isBinary()`